# How to display the number of grouped applications on the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

In Windows XP and Vista it was possible to know at a glance the number of taskbar grouped instances/opened windows for each application:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3] [image: 4]

For some reason this [feature has been removed in Windows 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7#Taskbar). Is there a way to reactivate it somehow, even if it requires third-party software?

Comment: It should be possible to write a utility that counts the number of running instances of each program and overlays it on the taskbar button, but so far I haven't come across one.

Comment: @Karan : I found [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-taskbar-indicate-the-number-of-combined/a9458f44-73c4-4ad9-bf6c-1ec5a442bf2f) but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Yes, I've seen that thread before but never tried the script. Seems like a kludge anyway to run it every time and I'd much rather use a small purpose-built utility instead.

Comment: @Karan : yes... for example what?

Comment: See my first comment. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done now with the help of [**7+ Taskbar Numberer**](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-numberer) (developed by RaMMicHaeL, who's also behind the brilliant [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)).

If you start the program with the **-v4** command-line parameter, it will display the number of grouped windows/taskbar buttons for each application as long as the program is running:

[image: 1]

If you start the program with the **-v5** command-line parameter, it will display the number of grouped windows/taskbar buttons for each application as long as the program is running and <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd> is *not* pressed. If <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd> is pressed, it will instead display the *position number* of each taskbar button group so that <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>Digit</kbd> can be used to activate each group:

[image: 2]

Comment: that tool is so good for some old_school users(not me), is good and use minimal resources.

Comment: Yes, it's a very nice bit of coding.

Comment: WOW, thank you man, accepted as solution (and I'm going to upvote your answer as soon as I can). I almost had lost hope and tried to manage the thing by myself in someway (see my answer) but the suggested application is clearly a better solution.

Comment: @danicotra: You're welcome, and as a bonus a nice utility I knew of has been improved even further. Win-win! :)

Answer (score 0):

After Karan answer I think this is a little bit useless now, yet having spent some time on it I decided to share it anyway.

As said before, the best way to suit the needing is an application that "enhances" Windows 7 taskbar in a way to make the number of grouped windows to show just within the relative icon, but it seemed nothing like that already existed so I thought about creating one by myself.
Well, I think the language to go in this case should be MS C++ .NET (not even C# could be suitable for the purpose I guess...) and since I'm definitely not skilled enough to achieve that by now (and I don't think I'll have the time for becoming anyway) the thing I did to get a sort of "acceptable" solution for my needs's been modify [this AHK script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/35867-winget-count-is-telling-me-i-have-6-windows-open-but/) as follow:

```
;;WARNING NOTE 1: does't count grouped open folders
;;WARNING NOTE 2: opened Windows Media Player counts as 4 instances
;;WARNING NOTE 3: count fails in the remote hypothesis that, for example, a folder named ".pdf - Adobe Reader" is open 
;; based on http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/35867-winget-count-is-telling-me-i-have-6-windows-open-but/

#SingleInstance, force 

Gui, add, text, , Windows count (including not grouped ones) = 
Gui, add, text, x+5 vcount, XX 
Gui, add, edit, xm r20 vWList w400 -wrap +0x100000 +readonly 
Gui, Show
GoSub, checklist

SetTimer, checklist, 3000 
return 

checklist: 
  WinGet, count, count
  WinGet,current,List 
  nocount = 0
  last_app_name = %A_Space%- %A_Tab% ; something that surely can't be used for files/folders file... Tip: anyway "Start" should always be the first element of the list
  myArray := Object()
  log = grouped applications instances:
  loop, %current% { 
    WinGetTitle, tTitle, % "ahk_id " current%A_Index% 
    if tTitle is space
    {
      nocount += 1 
    }
    else if (tTitle == A_ScriptName || tTitle == "Start" || tTitle == "Program Manager" || tTitle == "Default IME" || tTitle == "HTA Test" || tTitle = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe") ; note == for everything except = path as case may vary on different PCs
    {
      nocount += 1
    }
    else
    {
     temp_FoundP := InStr(tTitle, last_app_name, 0) 
     if ((temp_FoundP != 0 ) && (last_app_name == substr(tTitle, temp_FoundP) ))
     {
       myArray[last_app_name] += 1
     }
     else
     {
      temp_FoundP := InStr(tTitle, " - ", 0) 
      if (temp_FoundP != 0) {
        last_app_name := substr(tTitle, temp_FoundP)
      }
      else {
        last_app_name = %A_Space%- %A_Tab%
      }
      if myArray[last_app_name] {
        myArray[last_app_name] += 1
      }
      else { myArray[last_app_name] := 1
      }
     }
    } 
   } 
  remaindercount = 0
  For key, value in myArray
  {
;MsgBox %key% = %value% ; DELETE THIS LINE
    if (key == "-" || value == 1) {
      remaindercount += value
    }
    else {    
      log .= "`n" key " = " value 
    }
  }
  if remaindercount > 0
      log .= "`n(remaining = " remaindercount ")"
;  Sort, log, C   ; uncomment this to sort by name 
  count -= nocount
  GuiControl, , count, %count%
  GuiControl, , WList, %log% 
  return 

GuiClose: 
ExitApp
```

FINAL NOTE: this was my first time with AHK and I'm always in a hurry so my coding may not be "optimal" an fully tested... besides that there are some limitations (read warning notes).
Anyway, as said, I think this isn't useful anymore after Karan answer (that I accepted as solution) yet anyone able to suggest a more convenient way/solution (another similar application or some coding in a "more serious" programming language than AHK for instance... well, ok maybe this is more stackoverflow matter) is still welcome.
Many thanks.

Comment: Heh, funny you selected AHK. :) [This](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/124225-show-number-of-combined-taskbar-buttons-as-an-overlay/) is what I asked after reading your question. However I wasn't able to improve it sufficiently and wasn't satisfied with the results, so I requested RaMMicHaeL instead.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it recently but I feel AHK can be very useful especially for one-trick-ponyes when you need a quick and dirty one-specific-task utility but not only... The only negative aspect, for me, is the documentation that definitively needs some improvements... I find it a bit uncomfortable and think that some more examples, for instance, wouldn't do bad...

Comment: Oh yes, AHK/AutoIt can be quite useful indeed in many situations. Perhaps you misunderstood, I wasn't saying your choice was bad. I just thought it was a bit funny because AHK was just what I thought of too when I read your question, which is why I asked on their forum.

Comment: Haha, yes, yes, I understand what you meant... It's probably me writing something wrong if you thought I understood you where mocking me; I didn't, don't worry. I was only making some personal considerations about the potential of AHK (which I discovered in this occasion during my googling in search for a possible way to achieve what I needed) and its "not-so-comfortable" documentation

Comment: I agree with you there, the docs could definitely use improvement. Lots of programmers prefer coding to commenting and documenting the code I guess. :)